# @NamedQuery trying to fetch entity and related entity (@OneToOne relation) by related entity property

Tags: spring-data-jpa, one-to-one, named-query

There are two entities:

```
@Entity(name = "Account")
@Table(name = "accounts")
@NamedQuery(name = "findAccountByExtId",
            query = "SELECT a " +
                    "FROM Account a " +
                    "WHERE a.accountDetails.extId = :extId " +
                    "AND a.deletedAt IS NULL")
public class Account extends DeletableAudit {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private AccountDetails accountDetails;
```

and

```
@Entity(name = "AccountDetails")
@Table(name = "account_details")
public class AccountDetails extends DeletableAudit {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer accDetId;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_account")
    private Account parent;

    @Column
    private String extId;
```

1. Goal is to return `Account` and `AccountDetials` via the external ID. The program won't run due to error:
   `Failed to create query for method public abstract p.j.o.d.d.Account p.j.o.d.r.AccountRepository.findAccountByExtId(java.lang.String)! No property extId found for type Account!`

   Already tried different variations of `@OneToOne` mapping and query, however nothing seems to work.
2. Second question is whether it is possible to have `AccountDetails` reference the same ID as `Account`. I'd like to get rid of `accDetId` and just store these entities with the same UUID of their parent.

Comment: perhaps you should tag this as `spring-data-jpa` since these find methods are nothing at all to do with the JPA API and everything to do with Spring

Comment: @BillyFrost Done, Thx.